# is Bohr Model actually Wave Model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, atomic-physics

When we take the postulate that the angular momentum of the orbit is an integral multiple of h/4π
This postulate's result can be derived from de Broglie Equation

Does not this imply we implemented wave theory into Bohr model of atom?

Comment: This question is difficult to answer because it is so vague. "Wave theory" for example is not well-defined because there are a lot of waves in physics, many of which have their own theories. If the question is "does Bohr model include wave aspects" then the answer is clearly *yes*, but as it is I can't tell what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: yeah, I actually meant wave aspects like considering wave nature of electron